# How to move the zsh cursor after vi operator pending mode in a custom widget?

Tags: zsh

I develop a [zsh plugin](https://github.com/IngoHeimbach/zsh-easy-motion) which is a port of vim-easymotion for zsh in vi emulation mode. Since the zsh line editor has multiline support, I added support for line motions (`j` and `k`). The plugin should also work for vi operator pending mode (for example in deletion mode), so I used the `MARK` and `CURSOR` variables of zsh to extend the user selection to complete lines (so a line motion will always delete or change whole lines and not only parts of them). This is the behavior a vim user would expect. However, the cursor position after a change/deletion operation is wrong. The cursor should be on the first word on the next line **after** a deleted block of lines. Instead, the cursor is at the end of the last line **before** the block of lines. I don't see a possibility to change the cursor after the operator pending mode since any cursor change will be part of the region for the selected operator.

So my question is: Does anyone know how the cursor position can be changed in a zsh custom widget **after** a vi operator was executed?

**Update**:

To make the question understandable, I tried to create a minimal example of the problem:

This small zsh script can be sourced:

```bsh
function test-widget () {
    MARK=3
    CURSOR=6
}

zle -N test-widget

bindkey -M vicmd ' ' test-widget
```

If you are in zsh's vicmd/normal mode (`bindkey -v` to activate the vi emulation and `<esc>` to enter the command mode), you can now press `<space>` to set the cursor to the sixth character in the current edit buffer. If you enter a vi operator like `d` followed by `<space>`, everything from the third to the sixth character will be deleted (due to the setting of the `MARK` variable).

Deletion example:
Consider your edit buffer is (cursor position marked with `[]`):

```
[a]bc def ghi
```

and you press `d<space>`, you will get:

```
abc[f] ghi
```

However, I would like to change the position of the cursor after the deletion operation in the same widget call, e.g.:

```
abcf [g]hi
```

I don't know how this would be possible since all changes to `CURSOR` would affect the range of deleted text.

How can I achieve a deletion operation + a cursor positioning?

Comment: I have updated my question trying to make things a bit easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks. It's much clearer with that example. It sounds to me that you would have to wrap the widget bound to `d` (`vi-delete`) here. You could also try asking on the zsh-users mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me you would have to redefine the widgets that take a motion, like the ones bound to `d`, `c`, `y`, `gu`, `gU`, `g~`...

Something like:

```
test-widget () {
  MARK=3
  CURSOR=6
  MOVE_AFTER_MOTION=2
}
zle -N test-widget
bindkey -M vicmd ' ' test-widget

for widget in vi-{delete,change,yank,{down,oper-swap,up}-case}; do
  $widget () {
    local ret
    zle ".$WIDGET"; ret=$?
    if (($+MOVE_AFTER_MOTION)); then
      (( CURSOR += MOVE_AFTER_MOTION ))
      unset MOVE_AFTER_MOTION
    fi
    return "$ret"
  }
  zle -N $widget
done
```

You may also have to think of what to do when `$NUMERIC` is not 1.

Comment: Works perfectly for my use case, thanks!

Comment: Does substitute / `s` take a motion?

Comment: No, sorry my bad. Fixed now.